# Pass JVM argument with space in batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, jvm

I had batch script which executes ***TestRun*** class by taking jvm arguments as shown below

```
java -cp "./lib/*;./statoil.jar" -DURI=localhost:8080 -DOWUser=abc -DOWPassword=abc123 -DpipelineName=EDMStatOil -Ddatabase=edm -DproviderName=141Provider -DdestinationName=110EDM -DproviderWellName=Serno Grad com.statoil.rts.test.TestRun
```

But while running batch script getting error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Grad

I know it is treating Grad as class file. But how we can avoid this error while passing jvm argument with space?

Comment: Did you tried -DproviderWellName="Serno Grad" ?

Comment: tried with quotes. Even though it is reflecting same error as Error: Could not find or load main class Grad"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you batch file try setting the variable first and then pass that parameter to the actual command like these.

```
set WellName="Serno Grad"

java -cp "./lib/*;./statoil.jar" -DURI=localhost:8080 -DOWUser=abc -DOWPassword=abc123 -DpipelineName=EDMStatOil -Ddatabase=edm -DproviderName=141Provider -DdestinationName=110EDM -DproviderWellName=%WellName% com.statoil.rts.test.TestRun
```

OR

```
set WellName="Serno Grad"

java -cp "./lib/*;./statoil.jar" -DURI=localhost:8080 -DOWUser=abc -DOWPassword=abc123 -DpipelineName=EDMStatOil -Ddatabase=edm -DproviderName=141Provider -DdestinationName=110EDM -DproviderWellName="%WellName%" com.statoil.rts.test.TestRun
```

On my system either of them works fine.

Comment: tried with quotes. Even though it is reflecting same error as Error: Could not find or load main class Grad"

Comment: didn't work by setting variable also. Giving same error

Comment: not getting what's wrong with my script. I guess jvm version problem or OS problem. I am using jdk1.7.0_79 and windows server 2012 R2

Comment: No your command is correct. Problem is with escaping the whitespace character. I could replicate your problem by passing `Serno Grad` without quotes in the command line and batch file

Comment: You can try the same command with something like `Serno` instead of `Serno Grad` just to prove it

Comment: I tried without white space. It is working well and my command is correct. But the suggested solution is not working in my case with whitespace

Comment: Its really going wild now. Try with this `-DproviderWellName="\"Serno Grad\""`

Comment: There were two places where same argument Serno Grad is being called. I applied solution at both places. It worked now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't care if there is a space in the JVM argument's value, but the terminal will split `-DproviderWellName=Serno Grad` into two command line arguments and pass those to the java executable.

You have to put quotes around the whole argument:

```
java "-DproviderWellName=Serno Grad"
```

Comment: @Nazeer_hanne This should work - if it doesn't, then something else must be wrong. My first guess would be that it's an issue with the script file. Can you try to execute the command directly from the cmd instead of from a script?

Comment: yes, this worked. There were two places where same argument Serno Grad is being called. I applied solution at both places. Thank you

Comment: @Nazeer_hanne if this solved your issue, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

try with escape characters -DproviderWellName="\"Serno Grad\""